# Dataframes and looping

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I have a list of tickers (186) and for each I need to get prices... I am doing it with loops and for each ticker I want a new df numbered from 0 to 186.

for info: len(tickers_list)=186

```
for i in range(len(tickers_list)-180):
    try:
        data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(tickers_list[i], start=df['Date'][i], end="2020-08-30")['Adj Close']
        df_new[i]=pd.DataFrame(data)
    except:
        print('Fail')
        continue
```

I am only getting Fail. if I remove except the error message is
'df_new' is not defined

Comment: You're calling `df_new` before you've defined it by "slicing" it using `[i]`.

Comment: @HampusLarsson
not sure what you mean. How shall i fix it, pls?
I tried
`df_new=pd.DataFrame(data)
df_new[i]=df_new`

But it does not work either

Comment: If `df_new=pd.DataFrame(data)` doesn't work, that's probably DataFrame cannot deal with the result returned from `.get_data_yahoo()`. You should provide a complete example and mention the error you get. @HampusLarsson already answered for you current problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `get_data_yahoo` returns a `DataFrame` and you are selecting only the `'Adj Close'` column, you could collect all series in a dictionary and later concatenate them into a dataframe.

```
data = dict()

for i, (ticker, start_date) in enumerate(zip(tickers_list[:6], df.Date)): # a simpler way to iterate
    data[ticker] = pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start=start_date,
        end='2020-08-30')['Adj Close']

data = pd.concat(data.values(), keys=data.keys(), axis=1)
```

Comment: many thanks it works very well. I have another question, please... would it be possible to start each column with first non NaN value and then to index the rest of values of the columns as of percentage of the first non NaN value?

Comment: @Tomas it is hard to solve that in comments... I'm aure if you structure your idea you can find an answer here or in google, if you don't then post a new question, but please read the help section on [how to provide a good reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)